# Best practice to provide MySQL JDBC driver password

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jdbc, tomcat7

I have `JSP` web application deployed in `Tomcat7` server that use `MySQL` as a database. In database connection I'm currently providing clear text username and password as below.

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://hostname:3306/schema", "user", "password");
```

As a security requirement I cannot use plain text passwords in my code and I cannot use configuration files to store information ether so everything has to be in a database somewhere.

**Q1** As for this issue can I provide a hashed input for password field in connection string.?

**Q2** If I can't use file based configuration method which would be the best way to store sensitive information.?

Comment: http://java.dzone.com/articles/storing-passwords-java-web hope it helps

Comment: @Shriram It explain about hashing user passwords I think. I need to know can I use a hashed input for password field in JDBC connection string.

Comment: A hash in a cfg (which you can use to authenticate) won't be any more secure than the plain password (same goes for private keys, symmetrically encrypted password stores...). You should probably ask the guy who wrote the requirements about it.

Comment: @Vatev THank you for the information. but can I know that thr JDBC driver support for hashed input for password field.?

Comment: My point is that even if it does (which makes no sense to me) it doesn't matter. You will be storing the hash somewhere (same as the password) and an attacker who has access to it can still use it to authenticate.

Comment: Hashing the password will not help you, you need the actual password to do the login. If you don't want to store it in a config file or in the database in cleartext you can use a keyserver/oauth type setup to distribute the password to the server.

Comment: http://www.darkreading.com/database/database-encryption-depends-on-effective/240148441

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best approach is to define JDBC datastore in tomcat and then look it up in your web application. Following samples are shamelessly copied from tomcat [documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html). This way you do not have any passwords in your applicaion. The configuration is done by tomcat administrator, not by web application developer.

Context:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/TestDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
           maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
           username="javauser" password="javadude" 
           driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
           url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javatest"/>
```

web.xml

```
<resource-ref>
  <description>DB Connection</description>
  <res-ref-name>jdbc/TestDB</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
  <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

test.jsp

```
<sql:query var="rs" dataSource="jdbc/TestDB">
   select id, foo, bar from testdata
</sql:query>
```

servlet

```
Context initContext = new InitialContext();
Context envContext  = (Context)initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
DataSource ds = (DataSource)envContext.lookup("jdbc/TestDB");
Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
```

Regarding your security requirements: this is harder, because the password is plaintext there as well. You can limit access rights so only web container can read it. Encrypting password will not work with symmetrical ciphers because attacker can get them as well. And asymmetrical ciphers - he can get decode key too. So you must set up the environment that attacker will not see content of the configuration files. If he is root, everything is lost anyway.

Comment: With reference to 'encrypting' passwords, see this in the Tomcat FAQ http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Password